# React Native fetch data in MYSQL database

Tags: php

I'm using React Native and extracting data from MYSQL. But I can't get the direct result of my data. So the output that is now: "[{" STT_TIP ":" Taxi "}]", I would say that the output: "Taxi" get. So just give me the result. He's drawing his name in the painting I'm taking now. I just want to draw the result.

```
<?php
    include 'DBConfig.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_turkish_ci'");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $arr       = array();
    $json      = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj       = json_decode($json, true);
    $email     = $obj['email'];
    $password  = $obj['password'];
    $Sql_Query = "select STT_TIP from ...... where .. = '$email' and . = '$password' ";
    $result    = $conn->query($Sql_Query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tem  = $row;
            $json = json_encode($tem);
        }
    } else {

    }
    echo $json;
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You just want "Taxi" as the result ? Your SQL query always return 1 result ?

Comment: Yes, it only gives a result. His printout also includes the name of the table. Do not write the name of the table, just print the result output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said this only returnn 1 result. Don't bother with the loop

use

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // same as mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

and

```
$json = json_encode($row['STT_TIP');
```

Will return the same as plain text(no brace, nor object)

Be carefull, your code is vulnerbale to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you worked, how can I remove the quotation marks?

Comment: ltrim() will remove double quotes / str_replace can do the trick (but for that you'll need to not json_encode your result, return plain text will work too